If some hardware is removed, can the phone be still started up and the apps that don't depend to it functional?
I need to make a custom fit of a heatsink to the CPU which overheats quickly, but there is some stuff in the way which are useless for the customisation.
If I remove the components NFC and proximity sensor from the Android, just unclip the connector, etc., can I still start up the phone and use the other functions which do not need those sensors at all?

In my service experience, if you remove those components, the headset will work fine. If any app calls for the sensors, that function only will not work. So you are good to do it.

thats great!  thnx for the fast reply

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
